# GoCD issue when I run a C# application

Tags: c#, performancecounter, go-cd, go-server, go-agent

I am running a `C# tool` to test the Performance of deployed package and the tool tries to start `Performance counters` in the machine where the package is deployed. I am getting Exception while adding performance counters in that machine when I run the Tool through `GoServer`.

However, I am not facing any issues in this when I run the tool manually in command prompt.

> `Exception while capturning Performance Counter for Machine` occurs only when I run the tool through GoCD. I am not sure of what causes this issue.

Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Hi AVK, Please add more information about the **Exception** you're seeing to the question.

Comment: @RaviTezu: The tool tries to start the performance counters of an windows agent machine through RDP - When I run the tool in the machine, this works fine. But when I run it thru GoCD, it could not start the Performance counters and throws Exception

Comment: Please add the Excception information.